# ejabberd auto allow subscription

Tags: objective-c, chat, ejabberd

I have installed and run ejabberd successfully. I've tested the chat function and it works well.

I have a problem with the 'Add Buddy' process. When I add a buddy, the buddy has to manually approve the request. I would like to skip this step and have all buddy requests to be approved automatically.

I'm getting a presence type of 'subscribe' for authorization requests. How can I authorize a buddy programmatically? I'm using objective c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer to my question.

Basically, just follow the protocol on http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#sub and programmatically send a subscribe request.